# Buscar items con "basic_health" en la api de Mercado Libre

Tags: api, mercadolibre

Quisiera saber si existe algún recurso en la api de Mercado Libre (api.mercadolibre.com) que me permita filtrar los ítems de una cuenta por nivel de calidad (health): basic, standar, professional.
Hasta el momento sólo he encontrado ese filtro en el apartado de ventas/publicaciones pero quisiera hacerlo de forma programática.